# Resizing a tableView full screen when clicked

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I am working on the following :
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvO4B.png)

Basically it's one UIImageView inside of another UIImageView at the top (60% of the screen) and a UITableView that takes 40% of the screen

and code (see below) :

What I am trying to achieve is to resize the cells of the UITableView full screen when my customCell is clicked on and unsize it to it's original state when unclicked.

Is there any way to make this work?
Thanks in advance.

```
    //Label outlets

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath? = nil


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//MARK Start of CustomViewCell Code

    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CustomViewCell

    cell.clipsToBounds = true

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let index = indexPath

    if selectedIndexPath != nil {
        if index == selectedIndexPath {
            return 667
        } else {
            return 62
        }

    } else {

        return 62}
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    switch selectedIndexPath {
    case nil:
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    default:
        if selectedIndexPath! == indexPath {
            selectedIndexPath = nil
        } else {
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        }
    }

    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

}

    //MARK End of CustomViewCell Code
```

Comment: What is the content of your `tableViewCell` which you are going to make fullscreen? Does that have a `imageView`?

Comment: No @Santosh `labels`and `textView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides reloading the cells with the new heights, you also need to change the frame of the table view. If you want to make the table occupy the whole screen, make sure you create an IBOutlet for it, say myTableView, then, after:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

Add this code:

```
myTableView.frame = view.bounds
```

You may also create a Bool variable to keep track of normal and full-screen modes of the table view, and some CGRect variable to keep the initial frame. You may need something like this when you want the table view to go back to its initial frame:

```
myTableView.frame = initialTableViewFrame
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: You have lost me @ppalancia
I get the idea for resizing the `tableView`that I already declared as an IBOutlet, but then how do I let this same `tableView` be a Bool variable.
I have tried a few things but could'nt get it to work. If you know of a tutorial to walk me through that that'd be great. Please don't show me the complete solution since I want to understand as much as I can by myself. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @j0h4nf ... I meant a Bool variable/property inside your view controller that the table view belongs to. Will see if I get some time to write a tutorial for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure auto-layout approach:

1.In your interface builder, create a `UIImageView` with constraints [Trailing, Leading, Top , Bottom, Height], make the height >= and priority is 999. You will use this height later in code for the expand/collapse logic.
[image: Elements]
[image: Layouts]

2.Create a dummy UIView whose height will be programmatically set later, this UIView will 'push' / 'stretch' your cell height when you create the expand effect to your imageview. Set it's visibility to hidden since you don't need to show this to your user.
[image: Elemets]
[image: Layouts]

3.In your custom cell, create two `NSLayoutConstraint` instances as @IBoutlets, one for UIImageView height and one for the dummy UIView height then connect them later in your interface file.

```
let lowPriorityHeight : Float = 250;
let highPriorityHeight : Float = 999;
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imgVwHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var tempHeight : NSLayoutConstraint!
    var isExpanded = false{
        didSet{
            imgVwHeight.priority = (isExpanded) ? lowPriorityHeight : highPriorityHeight;
            if isExpanded == true{
                tempHeight.constant = ExpandedHeight
            }else{
                tempHeight.constant = NormalHeight
            }
        }
    }
```

4.In your main class, set the `isExpanded` to true or false to create the effect.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.isExpanded = !cell.isExpanded
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "kCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        return cell
    }
```

You may download my sample implementation [HERE](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/qoe22ria1ltc32s/TestSO.zip)

Comment: thanks @janusfidel but this isn't the solution I am looking for. I am really looking for a way to make it work the way I started.